ReferenceError: Property 'TextEncoder' doesn't exist
I'm using react native 0.72.4
I'm getting this error:  Reference Error: Property 'Text Encoder' doesn't exist at multiple places in my app. I didn't use it explicitly but my npm packages like qr-code-svg uses this package.
I don't know what Text Encoder is or where it is used .. i don't know why all of it occurs suddenly.

This question is similar to: Expo React Native Can't find variable: TextDecoder. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

They have fixed this issue with version 6.3.2
Update to this version and everything should work fine.
Ref:

https://github.com/grgia/react-native-qrcode-svg/issues/199
https://github.com/grgia/react-native-qrcode-svg/pull/200


this worked for me using same react native 0.72.4
install text-encoding using npm install --save text-encoding --legacy-peer-deps
then import it everywhere you have imported the qrcode like so
import 'text-encoding';
sample of how your code should look like when done with the install
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';
import 'text-encoding';

hope this helps!
